# ffmpeg transcoding process stops after 15min

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, transcoding, startupscript

im starting 2 ffmpeg transcoding processes on a raspberry pi (raspbian) when booting. After around 15 min, both processes stops. I have tried with delay etc. in startup script, also start it with both root and normal user privileges. Same result every time. (tried with rc.local and a own startup script in /init.d/)

my ffmpeg parameters are:

```
ffmpeg -d -re -i http://lyd.nrk.no/nrk_radio_mp3_mp3_m -ac 1 -acodec g722 -f rtp -ab 64k -ar 16k rtp://10.5.98.150:61122 > /dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null  &
sleep 15
ffmpeg -d -re -i http://lyd.nrk.no/nrk_radio_mp3_mp3_h -ac 1 -acodec g722 -f rtp -ab 64k -ar 16k rtp://10.5.98.150:61124 > /dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

If i start it manually after boot the ffmpeg processes works, and wont stop. Its only when i try to start it during boot it stops. (I have also tried with crontab, same result)

anyone have some ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe better suited to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you are using systemd, I'd say you are hitting the timeout in the activation of the local init scripts. Try using a proper systemd unit or a cronjob.